# Unable to search for a range of dates in SQL

Tags: java, sql

This is the database.

[image]

When I try to search for a range of issue dates, the data doesn't appear.

[image]

This is the code:

```
String sql = "select * from issuebook where issue_date BETWEEN ? AND ?";
PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);

pst.setDate(1, fromDate);
pst.setDate(2, toDate);

ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

if(rs.next() == false){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Record Not Found!");
}
else{
    while(rs.next()){
       String id = rs.getString("id");
       String bookname= rs.getString("book_name");
       String studentname= rs.getString("student_name");
       String issuedate = rs.getString("issue_date");
       String duedate = rs.getString("due_date");
       String status = rs.getString("status");
    
    
       Object[] obj = {id,bookname,studentname,issuedate,duedate,status};
       model =(DefaultTableModel) table_view_record.getModel();
       model.addRow(obj);
    }
```

Comment: That code's going to (if it returns >= 1 row) miss the first row: *if(rs.next() == false){* What, *exactly*, do you think is happening there? A clue to a cure: `while(rs.next()){ recordsFound = true;...`

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that only a single record fits the criteria (ID=9) and you are swallowing it with the if (rs.next() == false). I suspect you want rs.hasNext(), which returns a boolean.

You are always discarding the first record with the rs.next() test.

Comment: I mentioned that above ;)